# Create Cognitive Services (Face API) accounts programmatically

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Is it possible to create new Azure Cognitive Services (Face API) accounts from code?
I can provision new accounts via Resource Manager template, but how can I do it from C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by calling the ARM API (management.azure.com) using this syntax:

```
PUT /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/{accountName}?api-version=2016-02-01-preview
```

Documentation is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/cognitiveservicesaccounts.